# Understanding GitHub branches

Tags: git, github

I am trying to understand how GitHub works, in terms of makings commits from different branches. I am looking at a repository which I want to clone. Let's say the address is `https://github.com/dartsim/alpha`. Now, there are two branches: `Master`, and `V2`, and the code I want is in the `V2` branch. If I navigate the `V2` file structure in the GitHub website, it takes me to the address `https://github.com/dartsim/dart/tree/V2`. Now, if I download the ZIP file from this webpage, it gives me the `V2` code as needed. However, on this same `V2` webpage, it also shows the address to use if you want to clone the repository, which is shown as `https://github.com/alpha/alpha.git`. However, when I clone this, it downloads the code from the old `Master` branch, rather than the `V2` branch.

Please could somebody explain why this webpage is not showing a download link for the `V2` branch? Why is this default download link for the old version of the code, rather than the newer version? Thanks!

Comment: you're cloning the repo not the branch, if you do `git checkout V2`after cloning the repo, you will have the V2 branch code. The link in Github, is purely for cloning and not for checking out specific branches. A clone always takes the entire repo.

Comment: Just change the branch on the clone.  All clones include all branches.  Under the covers In GIT branches (and even versions) are an abstraction on top of the file data.

Answer (score 0):

The default branch is by default 'master' - but you can set that up in the Github repository settings page.

The download link at Github is a snapshot of the active branch - a git export.

Git is distributed and that means that when you clone, you get a complete copy of the repository, all branches/tags/whatever included.

You can list the branches by running `git branch` and switch to a branch by doing `git checkout name-of-branch`.

If you want a quick tutorial on git, see [git - the simple guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

And, of course, you ought to read the official git docs (they are great):

[Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/documentation)